# PHP MySQL Insert INTO...ON Duplicate Key Update Where

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-insert, on-duplicate-key

I need to insert when rows don't exist in the tickets table and/or update when rows do exist with 1 query.

I tried the following and it doesn't add new records and it doesn't up the existing records.

```
$query_upsert = mysqli_query($mysqli, 
    "INSERT INTO tickets (
        ticket_companyname,
        ticket_ordernumber,
        ticket_datetimedeliverydate,
        ticket_ritech,
        ticket_ticketstatus
    )
    SELECT 
        nextgenorder_companyname, 
        nextgenorder_ordernumber,
        nextgenorder_deliverydate,
        '$ticket_ritech',
        '$ticket_ticketstatus'
    FROM nextgenorders2 
    WHERE 
        nextgenorder_companyname LIKE CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX('$nextgenorder_companyname', ' ', 1),'%') 
        AND nextgenorder_deliverydate='$nextgenorder_deliverydate'
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE,
         ticket_companyname='$ticket_companyname',
         ticket_ordernumber='$ticket_ordernumber',
         ticket_datetimedeliverydate='$ticket_datetimedeliverydate',
         ticket_ritech='$ticket_ritech',
         ticket_ticketstatus='$ticket_ticketstatus'
    WHERE
        ticket_companyname LIKE CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX('$nextgenorder_companyname', ' ', 1),'%') 
        AND ticket_datetimedeliverydate='$nextgenorder_deliverydate'
    )"
);
```

Can you use WHERE clause in a upsert query? I have all errors on and i'm not getting any errors.

Please help.

Thanks,

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add any data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or data *of any kind* directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Note: The [object-oriented interface to `mysqli`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php) is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface where missing a single `i` can cause trouble. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era and should not be used in new code.

Comment: This query is pretty hard to read due to the verbosity. Can you trim down the number of fields present to a more minimal version of same? if you're not getting any errors, are you sure you're checking for them? Are they being logged? Try running the query `"SELECT this should not work"` and if you don't get an error you have to fix that first.

Comment: i'll do that righ tnow

Comment: When tackling big queries like this I try and build it up in stages. Test each component, observe it behaves correctly, and then add on incrementally more, keeping a copy of each intermediate form. That way if you mess something up badly you have a checkpoint to fall back to.

Comment: I just stripped it down, is that easier to read?

Comment: Now that we don't have to scroll, much better.

Comment: Get rid of the `WHERE` clause at the end of the query, after `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...`. It's not valid syntax. `ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE
         ticket_companyname LIKE CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX('$nextgenorder_com' at line 58`

Comment: Does the inner `SELECT` work in isolation?

Comment: Yes it does, i previously had a query to count if company name exists, if 0 insert, if more than 0 then update. Which works on insert but it doesnt add new rows on the update.

Comment: Perhaps you could explain what you think this extra `WHERE` clause will do?

Comment: Lets say company ABC has 3 records on the source table yesterday but today it has 10 new records. The destination table only has the 3 records from yesterday. Now when i run the query, i want it to update the 3 records and also add the 10 new records. I added the WHERE clause so it knows to update those existing records and then insert the new records that were just added to the source table

Comment: `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` will perform the requested update on any record where a column with a unique constraint would be duplicated, otherwise it will create new entries. I'm not following what your desired behaviour is, but it may be better achieved in your PHP code.

Comment: How come we got a fiddle last time but not this time?

Comment: i'll make a fiddle now. Please standby.

Comment: I concur the WHERE at the end is a problem. Also the comma after "UPDATE"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problems and possible improvements with your query:

- it has two `WHERE` clause: you want only one, which should appear after the `SELECT` clause
- you are wide open to SQL injection you should use bind parameters
- you don't need to repeat the parameter in the right side of the assignments: instead, you can use the `VALUES` syntax
- Also I think that you are trying to update too many fields in the `ON DUPLICATE KEY` clause, I removed some of them and let those that I thought were relevant (essentially, you don't need to update the columns that come into play to check for conflicts)

Consider:

```
INSERT INTO tickets (
    ticket_companyname,
    ticket_ordernumber,
    ticket_datetimedeliverydate,
    ticket_ritech,
    ticket_ticketstatus
)
SELECT 
    nextgenorder_companyname, 
    nextgenorder_ordernumber,
    nextgenorder_deliverydate,
    ?,                          --> query parameter for "ticket_ritech"
    ?,                          --> ... "ticket_ticketstatus"
FROM nextgenorders2 
WHERE 
    nextgenorder_companyname 
        LIKE CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(?, ' ', 1),'%') --> ... "nextgenorder_companyname"
    AND nextgenorder_deliverydate = ?               --> ... "nextgenorder_deliverydate"
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE,
    ticket_ritech = VALUES(ticket_ritech)
    ticket_ticketstatus = VALUES(ticket_ticketstatus)
```

Comment: They're using mysqli_, not PDO.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner: ah, yes. I changed for positional parameters. Thank you!

Comment: The insert section works but the update doesnt. If I run the query, it inserts duplicate records instead of updating the existing ones.

Comment: This worked after changing the serial number column to a unique column. Thank you for your help.